# Keyboard moving screen issue net maui

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, mobile, maui

I ran into a problem. Im trying to use keyboard, but when I use entry or editor, the keyboard is moving the entire page content upwards. Does anybody know how to turn this behavior off? Or some walkaround? Is it possible to get the keyboard height or some keyboard properties?

Here is my xaml code:

```
    <ScrollView Grid.Row="1">
        <VerticalStackLayout>
            <Rectangle HeightRequest="200" BackgroundColor="Red" Margin="10"/>
            <Rectangle HeightRequest="200" BackgroundColor="Red" Margin="10"/>
            <Rectangle HeightRequest="200" BackgroundColor="Red" Margin="10"/>
            <Rectangle HeightRequest="200" BackgroundColor="Red" Margin="10"/>
        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <Border Grid.Row="2"
            HeightRequest="45" Stroke="Transparent" StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 20"
            StrokeThickness="0" Margin="10,0,10,0" VerticalOptions="End">
        <Grid 
                BackgroundColor="#606060" ColumnDefinitions="*,auto">
            <Editor
                    x:Name="EntryElement" Grid.Column="0" Placeholder="Search" 
                    Margin="10,0" IsSpellCheckEnabled="False" IsTextPredictionEnabled="False"
                    TextColor="White">
                <Editor.Behaviors>
                    <toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior Command="{Binding EntryTextChangedCommand}" EventName="TextChanged"/>
                </Editor.Behaviors>
            </Editor>
        </Grid>
    </Border>


    <view:Header_details/>

</Grid>
```

Comment: Which platforms does this affect? In your XAML or code-behind do you use any platform-specific code? This might be of interest: [Soft Keyboard Input Mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/android/platform-specifics/soft-keyboard-input-mode).

Comment: This affects Android. I tried the thing you sent, but doesn't work for me. As I said, I would at least appreciate to know, how to get the keyboard height, this would be the best walkaround.

Comment: There are few thousand issues in MAUI, and like half of them are about this Android keyboard. I can search it for you if you cant find it.

Comment: I would extremely appreciate that. I was searching for two days and no useful help has been found.

Comment: Is it possible to override the entry class and somehow control the keyboard class through the entry class?

Comment: @siflJebatkundy You can use `custom renderer`  or  `handler`to override the entry class. Here's a [sample code](https://github.com/pulmuone/MauiAndroidKeyboard/blob/master/MauiAndroidKeyboard/Platforms/Android/Handlers/CustomEntryHandler.Android.cs) for your reference.